# Text with different font filling in XOR pattern or fills in places that should not be filled

Tags: text-object

When using the font "Cabin", the fill does not work correctly. (see image)

I have tried all the fill modes and all relevant geometry settings to no avail.

[image: image of the text "0123456789" but 3 to 9 have some sort of xor issue, and 4 and 7 is filled incorectly]
[image: The text with no face. (only edge)]

Comment: The font has overlapping geometry because of the triangles in places like two of the inside corners of the 4.  This is confusing the geometry engine into not understand what is inside the numeral.

Comment: I get that but is there no way to fix this? other programs can handle it.

Comment: Fonts aren't something Blender handles well.  Hopefully someone else will know how to fix it for this one.  I'm sorry I don't.